# How to show surrounding parents in d3 treemap?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I would like to show the surrounding parents when I zoom into my treemap, as shown here:

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2010/02/01/us/budget.html?_r=0

In this NYT visual (which is unfortunately in Flash), when you zoom in to a section, you can still see its surrounding sections. I'd like to create the same experience for my d3 Zoomable Treemap, but am not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Alternative link to the budget proposal visualization (no flash)
http://www.nytimes.com/packages/html/newsgraphics/2011/0119-budget/

Answer (score 1):

I would try reverse engineering [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) and see how far you get. Then you can ask more specific questions concerning more specific issues you are having with your code.